# How do I access this ArrayList from another class?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a newbie in java and I have to do a "array project" for college. I'm having trouble getting the array in my Main class from Contacts class where it is stored. This is what I've done for now:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // View Contact Testing
        Contacts contactObj = new Contacts();
        System.out.println(contactObj);
    }
}
```

```
public class Contacts {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("name1");
        arr.add("name2");

        return arr.clone();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get this error: *Error:(11, 25) java: incompatible types: unexpected return value*.
Any help would be much appreciated, 
Thanks

Comment: You cannot return something from the main method since it is declared as void (which means there is nothing to be returned!).

Comment: You have two main functions, only need one https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_classes.asp , store a array on contacts and them a getter, good look! you have a long ride

Comment: There are many things about basics of Java. I would say you need to read about return type of a method, main method it self and how to access members/methods.

Comment: I would suggest you read more about java class and methods, but to nudge you further here, `static void main(String[] args)` is main entry point for the java application. So "ideally" you would have only one `main` method per java application. Try changing method name of `Contacts` class to `getStudentList()` and in `Main` class. try calling `contactObj.getStudentList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by others I also advice you study a little bit more in some basic Java tutorials (there is a several spread over www). But also I understanding your struggling and will give you a few example that how you could do that. Follow:

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Contacts contactObj = new Contacts();
        contactObj.getNames().forEach(System.out::println);

        contactObj.cleanNames();
        contactObj.getNames().forEach(System.out::println);

        contactObj.addName("John");
        contactObj.addName("Maria");

        contactObj.getNames().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Contacts.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Contacts {

    private List<String> names;

    //either to help your understanding and for sake of simplicity
    public Contacts() {
        this.names = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.names.add("name1");
        this.names.add("name2");

    }

    //clean the content of names from names List
    public void cleanNames(){
        if (Objects.nonNull(names)) {
            this.names.clear();
        }
    }

    //add a name to list
    public void addName(String name) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(names)) {
            this.names.add(name);
        } else {
            this.names = new ArrayList<>();
            this.names.add(name);
        }
    }

    //set a entire list to names attribute
    public void setNames(List<String> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    //get the name attribute
    public List<String> getNames() {
        if (Objects.nonNull(names)) {
            return this.names;
        } else {
            this.names = new ArrayList<>();
            return names;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot ;) One question though, why do you have 3 console outputs in Main?

Comment: Hi thanks for feedback, I put the three outputs just to you understanding what could happen when you use the list in diff moments: just after construct the class, after clean the content of list and after add some values. Sum up just to didactic

Comment: `Contacts contactObj = new Contacts();
contactObj.getNames().forEach(System.out::println);` should this return all names in the list?

Comment: Yes, it print each one of names on default's console